# When a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth of compact support

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, smooth-functions, schwartz-space

The following statement is from the book " The analysis of linear partial diffential operators I by Lars Hörmander page 252

> If $v \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R^n})$ ( $v$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$) we can decide whether $v$ is in $C_0^\infty $ by examining the behavior of the Fourier transform $\hat{v}$ at $\infty$ . In fact, if $v \in C_0^\infty$ then $$ |\hat{v}(\xi)| \leq C_N {(1+ |\xi|)}^{-N}, \quad N =1,2,..., \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n,$$
> By lemma 7.1.3. Conversely, if the inequality above is fulfilled then $v \in C_0^\infty$ by Fourier's inversion formula.

Why does the Fourier's inversion formula imply that $v \in C_0^\infty$? And why we could decide whether $v$ is in $C_0^\infty$ by examining the behavior of the Fourier transform $\hat{v}$ at $\infty$?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $v$ is continuous because $\hat{v}$ is $L^1$. And $\partial_{x_1} v$ is continuous because $2i\pi \xi_1 \hat{v}$ is $L^1$. etc.

Comment: The proof of the Paley-Wiener theorem for test functions explains how the compact support of $v$ arises from the behavior of $\widehat{v}$. The version for compactly-supported distributions is also illuminating... Is this a suitable viewpoint for you?

Comment: @paul garrett, thank you for your comment! I'll read the proof of the theorem you mentioned, and ask you in case I don't get the point I'm looking for.

Comment: @reunis, thank you for your comment! I'm sure my question is stupid , but why is $\hat{v}$ in $L^1$ ?

Comment: @asma $0<|\hat v (\xi)| <C_{N+2} \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|)^{N+2}}$, and the latter function belongs to $L^1(\Bbb R^N)$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, ooops that was so simple but I didn't see it ! thank you so much for your help and have a nice day :)

Comment: Does $C^\infty_0$ indicates compact support or just vanishing to $0$ at infinity ?